# View counter off the rocker?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

According to the view counter, my question

[How to substitute eggs in homemade pasta?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/recipes-for-egg-free-homemade-pasta)

asked this afternoon, has been viewed *1,261 times*. The view count seems to rise and rise in between page refreshes, too.

Meanwhile, the hottest question in the "hot" tab has *80 views.*

This seems ridiculous. How can this be?

> **Update:** Now, 12 minutes later, the count is at 1,324.
>
> **Update:** Now, 18 minutes later, it's at 1,360.
>
> **Update:** Now, the next day, the massive growth seems to have stopped at 1,437.

Just so you know, I'm not giving back my "popular question" badge! :)

Comment: We actually had a *meta* question that managed to pick up 100 views in an hour.  Either something's wonky, or we're suddenly getting a lot of attention from *someone*.

Comment: Maybe it's just a fascinating question? My flaming banana question has over 2300 views in 2 days, which I can't really explain either. But it's very spotty which question have had the huge bumps. So my guess is that @aaronut is right, and someone *with a following) is sending users to some targeted questions. I just hope I can get the 2.5k views for the next badge. ;o) Would it be wrong to offer a bounty just to bump the view count?

Comment: @yossarian: Keep in mind we do have the Stack Exchange dropdown at the top which occasionally links people in from Stack Overflow and other large sites.  They might not be inclined to visit a "hot" question about egg substitutions, but "banana on fire" probably piqued a lot of people's curiosities.

Comment: @Aaronut: Do mods have tools to look at where the traffic is coming from? I seem to remember a mod on rpg.se that commented to that end.

Comment: @aaronut, what's wrong with egg substitutions?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it, @yossarian, it just doesn't have the "I gotta check this out" factor that a banana on fire (or anything on fire) does.

Comment: Yet another band name: Egg Substitution and the Flaming Bananas. I figure they play folky rock music.

Comment: Maybe it's a crowd of online veganistas who manage to drum up thousands of views whenever a question is about replacing an animal product with a vegetable-based one :)

Comment: @aaronut, tongue in cheek doesn't come across on the internet.

Comment: @Roux, awesome name! Are you sure they don't play yolk rock?

Comment: @yossarian- Now we need a "flag this comment as terrible pun" button. :)

Comment: @sobachatina, comments like that are just going to egg me on.

Comment: Aw shell, white have I started here? These puns are just going to keep coming up ova and ova. Lay it to rest, will you?

Comment: A resounding THWACK!!! to the lot of you. Faugh. :p

Comment: @Martha was that the sound of an egg dropping on the floor? :)

Comment: Not on the floor, no. You'll notice the dripping any minute now. ]:)

Answer (score 2):

There were some bugs in viewcount for a while; we scaled all affected viewcounts in the time interval back to adjust after the bug was fixed.

Comment: So glad my [2.5k question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/why-did-my-banana-catch-fire-in-the-microwave) (and silver badge) weren't effected! Maybe someone could jump over there and give hobodave the [1 vote he needs](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/why-did-my-banana-catch-fire-in-the-microwave/7743#7743) for another silver medal...